# Как происходит чтение страницы с диска при старте процесса?

Tags: cpu, ram, виртуальная-память

Опишу конкретную ситуацию.

При старте процесса CPU выдает виртуальный адрес.

Пусть TLB у нас будет пуст. Таблица страниц тоже не содержит необходимых записей (или хотя бы есть одна пустая запись таблицы страниц самого верхнего уровня иерархии с битом валидности 0). В оперативной памяти необходимого страничного блока нет.

Вопрос: как с помощью виртуального адреса мы сможем извлечь с диска страницу? Ведь мы не сможем просмотреть все страницы и найти по смещению информацию. А индекс в виртуальном адресе нам не поможет. 
Как быть именно на старте процесса, когда TLB и PT пусты?

Answer (score 2):

Что вы имеете ввиду под "процесс", если обычный процесс который работает под управлением операционной системы, то таблица страниц не будет пуста. При старте процесса операционная система прочитает в свои буфера начало выполнимого файла из заголовка, поймет какие сегменты и какого размера необходимо выделить для выполнения процесса, выделит блоки свободной оперативной памяти, построит таблицы страниц, при необходимости построит дескрипторные таблицы сегментов. После чего прочитает с диска необходимые блоки, подгрузит библиотеку загрузчика, который в свою очередь (с помощью функций ОС) догрузит необходимые библиотеки и настроит связи. После этого управление будет передано процессу, к этому моменту все таблицы уже будут существовать. А TLB будет просто очищен в момент передачи управления из ядра ОС в пространство процесса и набран CPU автоматически в процессе работы на основании информации из таблиц страниц.

Обратите внимание, CPU сам не выдает никаких адресов, это делает операционная система, основываясь на своих собственных, внутренних таблицах трансляции адресов ОЗУ в адреса например swap раздела или файла отраженного на память.